# Perfect Machine for blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

i've been searching for the perfect machine for blender.. the highest rated production level machine,that break up mentioned on blender site.

I cant go so much in to technical depth of pc components. in some parts something is lacking and something is up to the mark . its difficult to chose. So my question is very simple.

If i buy Apple MacBook Pro – MJLT2 would that be the perfect machine for blender in all aspects.Would i be able to do every ting from sculpting to rendering pretty easily on that machine? Specs for the mac book are below.

• 2.5GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.7GHz
• 16GB DDR3 RAM - 1600
• 512GB SSD Flash Storage
• Intel Iris Pro Graphics + AMD Radeon R9 M370X with 2GB GDDR5 memory

Comment: can u link me the one asked before?

Comment: Questions about hardware recommendations are **off topic** as is impossible to give  good answers that are not opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are two criteriae for the machine: speed of the UI and 3D-tools and speed of the renders. For the UI you are very well covered. (I have been desperately sculpting with dyntopo on a 15-year old two-core no physical (integrated or other) graphics card (I had to virtualize an old OpenGL-compatible card). It was awful, but OK for the very desperate cases)

So everything 3D or UI, you are good. Then there is rendering. If you want to render with Cycles, you want to use a CUDA enabled (ie. Nvidia-brand) graphics card. There should be changes to this on the way, but for now that's the deal. So while you would have a powerful graphics card, you couldn't practically use the card for rendering.

Comment: thank you for your input.. any recommendations? i haven't bought that machine yet

Comment: Please, don't trust me. I just wanted to point out that flaw as quickly as possible.

Comment: And by "don't trust me" I mean: don't trust me for choosing a computer for you.